# SQL how to pull out data which has commas without them?

Tags: sql, date, parsing, db2

In the database there is date put into fields with commas like `20,151,112` `(yy,yym,mdd)` which stands for date `12-11-2015`.

I need to take out the date and filter it so that I have only records from a period of time.

Do you know how I can pull out the data without the commas so I have integers which I can compare then?

Comment: side note: don't store dates like that.

Comment: I know, I did not create the db...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the commas using `REPLACE`, and then convert to a date using `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` and `DATE`:

```
DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(REPLACE(col, ',', ''), 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

e.g.

```
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(REPLACE('20,151,112', ',', ''), 'YYYYMMDD')) AS "theDate"
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Another solution is: `SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(dateField,1,3), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(dateField,4,4), SUBSTRING(dateField,8,3))) AS "date" FROM myTable`